# Why click() for element doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension

There's site called [steamgifts.com](http://www.steamgifts.com/). You can join to giveaways and got a small chance to win steam game. Some guy wrote Google Chrome extension ([Easy SteamGifts)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/easy-steamgifts/cklbilaeedbblhpkhjfcnmaocjdodcnm) for site which improves and optimize some actions.

I wanna write script which does all completely automatically.

Extension adds join buttons on site:

[image]

After I click on it extension opens background tab, do something and then close tab.

*How I can click on it programmatically?*

I trying different ways (eg):

```
$(".giveaway__row-outer-wrap.esg").find(".esg-join > a").trigger("click");
```

or just

```
$(".giveaway__row-outer-wrap.esg").find(".esg-join > a").click();
```

or even

```
$(".giveaway__row-outer-wrap.esg").each(function(){
        $(this).find(".esg-join > a").click();
});
```

All executes w/o errors (in Chrome console) but do nothing. I have thinking that is wrong element or something with classes... idk.

But if I change `click()` to (e.g.) `css("color", "blue");` it works completely fine.

[image]

What I do wrong?

Comment: Is your `<a>` link dynamically generated? or already in `DOM`?

Comment: jQuery explicitely avoid calling `click()` DOM method on anchor tag for browser normalization, maybe that's your issue. So try e.g: `$(".giveaway__row-outer-wrap.esg").find(".esg-join > a").each(function(){this.click();});` . `this.click()` not `$(this).click()`

Comment: @ParthTrivedi button appear with extension, so I think answer is dynamically.

Comment: @evlogii But what do you get for `console.log($(".giveaway__row-outer-wrap.esg").find(".esg-join > a").length);`?  {*cute kid!*}  ***EDIT:*** `But if I change click() to (e.g.) css("color", "blue"); it works completely fine.` So ya elements are available... Try my first comment

Comment: @A.Wolff It works! Thanks :-)

Comment: @A.Wolff can you elaborate me `$(this)` vs `this`? Get it as answer and explain that in answer. so he can get you marked answer.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi `$(this)` returns jQuerry object. Just `this` returns DOM object.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi I marked it as dupe instead because now anyway OP's issue has been fixed

Comment: @A.Wolff yup thats fine.